# Variable Always Returned as False

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, and there's probably a simple solution to this problem.  I have the following code written, but no matter what, the variable jan is always returned as false.

```
Dim month1 As Integer
Dim month2 As Integer
Dim month3 As Integer
Dim month4 As Integer
Dim jan As Boolean

If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.[K29]) Then month1 = month(Sheet1.[K29])
If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.[K30]) Then month2 = month(Sheet1.[K30])
If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.[K31]) Then month3 = month(Sheet1.[K31])
If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.[K32]) Then month4 = month(Sheet1.[K32])

If month1 > 1 Or month2 > 1 Or month3 > 1 Or month4 > 1 Then jan = False
```

I've tested the variables month1, month2, etc. indivdually and all seems well, except for the conditional at the end.  Even when all variables =1, jan is still false.

Thoughts?

Comment: `False` is the default value for `Boolean` variables.

Comment: you are just defining `jan`and never referencing it again, how should it become `true`?

Comment: @UGP I created a command to enter text into a cell if true and false to test it.  Jan is referenced in the conditional statement in the last line.

Comment: `jan` starts up being `false` ... your code does not set it to `true`

Comment: Totally makes sense now, thanks all for your advice!

Comment: Just `Dim jan As Boolean = True` will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try it like this...

```
If month1 > 1 Or month2 > 1 Or month3 > 1 Or month4 > 1 Then
    jan = False
Else
    jan = True
End If
```

Comment: Ah, that worked! I didn't realize it needed and "else jan=true"; I thought that was inherent in a boolean variable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can do `jan = not  (month1 > 1 Or month2 > 1 Or month3 > 1 Or month4 > 1)`